# RTP h.264 stream switcher

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264, rtp

I need to switch between two (or more) RTP streams. So I created silly example on Python, which reads from a UDP sockets RTP packets and sends packets from one of the sources to a destination. Then, on input from user it switches to another source.

I looked into RTP packet format, and I "fix" them so they look to come from the same source: sequence number, timestamp, ssrc.

It streams perfectly until sources are switched. Some players (VLC) stop playing altogether, some (ffplay) introduces a ton of latency.

I don't see what else in the packet could break the players...

Comment: Are these RTP streams using the same video format settings (codec, width, height, FPS, etc)?